# xsl:call-template: return a number rather than text to be assigned to a variable

Tags: templates, xslt, return-value, variable-assignment

I'm having a (minor) problem here. I'm calling a named template and am assigning the outcome to a variable. So for so good, but I need the type of the processed template's return value to be integer rather than text.

I wonder if there's a way to achieve that without having to go with a temporary variable?

Here's some sample code:

```
<xsl:variable name="tmp">
    <xsl:call-template name="mytemplate">
        <xsl:with-param name="x" select="123"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="myvar" select="number($tmp)"/>

<xsl:template name="mytemplate">
    <xsl:param name="x"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$x"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Don't mind the code as it is an oversimplification of what my template does. Notice also that I've tried to return `<xsl:value-of select="number($x)"/>` but to no avail.

Any help is heavily appreciated.
TIA

Comment: You might want to check whether an XSLT 2.0 processor is available for your system or platform, with XSLT 2.0 you can use `xsl:sequence` http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#constructing-sequences and you can use the `as` attribute http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-template to ensure a certain type is returned.

Comment: Thanks Martin, too bad XSLT 2.0 isn't an option here ... PHP - do I need to say more?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `$tmp` data type is Result Tree Fragment. So, besides copying, in all allowed operations with `$tmp`, only counts its string value.

XPath have many rules for implicit casting. In general, whenever an operator or function takes a number data type as argument, the expression will be cast to number with `number()` function.

Bottom line: in mostly every case you don't need that explicit casting.

Comment: In this case I need explicit casting because `not($tmp)` will be `false` even if `$tmp = "0"`. I know I've got a couple of other options to test - say e.g. `$tmp = 0`. Maybe it's just an aesthetic tic of mine but I'd rather use the `not` operator.

Comment: @aefxx: Your comment should be in question, then. Also not that an implicit boolean casting over number it's not a good choice...

Comment: @Alejandro: You're right, not a good choice either. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**As @Alejandro points out, you don't need explicit casting to number**.

If you intend to use this not as a number, but to use the number-representation as an intermediate type, then you do need the cast, because the RTF that is in the `$tmp` variable may not be directly convertible to that type as wanted.

**Example**:

You need:

```
  boolean(number($tmp))
```

to convert an RTF or any tree to a boolean tat can have two different values.

```
boolean(someNode)
```

is always `true()`  -- **[by definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-boolean)**.